# iCloud Keychain not syncing to Mac

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, keychain

I've been using iCloud for many services such as Notes, Reminders, iCloud Drive and Keychain for a long time withh my Mac, iPhone and iPad.

A few weeks ago, I've noticed that new passwords have not been syncing to my Mac if I've registered somewhere on my iPhone.

I'v disabled iCloud Keychain, restarted, re-enabled it from here:

[image]

I've waited for hours on Wifi, plugged in etc, no avail.

Then I've tried logging out of iCloud on my Mac completely and logging in back again. I've got a confirmation on my iPhone for 6-digit number, took a few minutes to re-enable it, entered my passwords etc. In a few minutes everything including my iCloud Drive files, Notes, Reminders were back on my Mac, but my keychain is still not here. It's again been hours (plugged in, connected to Wifi) but here is my keychain on my Mac:

[image]

All the contents of my iCloud Keychain is available on my iPhone, and it has iCloud Keychain enabled too:

[image]

I've left both my Mac and iPhone plugged in, fully charged, connected to Wifi for hours, but I'm still not getting anything on my Mac.

How do I get my keychain back on my Mac (without resetting, of course)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting the keychain folder which is localised under `~/Library/Keychains`
After deleting it, restart a device and enable iCloud keychain.